# MS Access VBA Selenium .getText after Submitting Form / WebPage

Tags: vba, selenium, web-scraping, ms-access-2016

Access 2016, just switched from I.E DOM to Selenium /Chrome : )  Need to get eBay listing ID Number after auto submitting Form/WebPage -this part works really sweet!  Getting runtime 428 "Object doesn't support this property or method" with either XPath or Css lines below.  The getItemID value on error shows as a null ( getItemID = "" )

```
    Select Case [Forms]![SettingsForm]![ListingOptionsFrame]
    Case 1
       'Listing Item --------------- AutoListOption------------------------- 
   Dim getText As String
   Me.ItemID = getItemID

   driver.FindElementByXPath("//input[@value='List item']").Click  
   PauseTimed (10)  'submitting Listing to eBay     

   getText = driver.FindElementByXPath("//*@id='Email']").getAttribute("data-itemid") '.getText() in place of .getAttribute 428's 
  'getText = driver.FindElementByCss("#Email").getAttribute("data-itemid") '.getText() in place of .getAttribute 428's as well 
Case 2
```

ebay's HTML -shortened for brevity. Need the "value" from data-itemid.

```
   <a id="Email" ...... data-itemid="143211121121"></a>
```

Can also get the "value" from a < span> if necessary. I had similar 428 errors as well and would need to use a Right() to get the "value".

A thought? Could the 428 error's be coming from the page reload or a popup after submitting? The page's address doesn't change. If you could point me in a direction it would be much appreciated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method in vba selenium is simply `Attribute()` and your existing error code should have been 438.

```
driver.FindElementByXPath("//*@id='Email']").Attribute("data-itemid")
```

You are working with a webElement which, for VBA implementation, has different syntax. When working with a node in IE, via Microsoft Internet Controls, you use the `getAttribute` syntax, which is the same naming as the javascript method of the `Element` interface.

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Example()
    Dim d As WebDriver
    Const URL As String = "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors"

    Set d = New ChromeDriver

    With d
        .Start "Chrome"
        .get URL

        Debug.Print .FindElementByCss("#edit-history-menu").Attribute("type")

        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: QHarr you were correct about  it being 438.  Too close to the screen error after trying to solve this...  Works great.  Thank You for your time.